# Why are electrons pictured to be revolving around the nucleus in Bohr's model

Tags: history-of-chemistry

Why exactly was it guessed by Bohr that electrons do revolve around nucleus in orbits than stay stationary around it in some discreet locations corresponding to a specific energy, or go around some other point or path. I believe stationary electrons in the electric field of the nucleus should also posses energy.

Comment: ... and would accelerate towards each other until collision?

Answer (score 2):

I took the liberty of changing the tag to "history of chemistry", because that's the only context in which Bohr's model is still relevant. With that in mind, let's move on.

Sure, a bunch of stationary electrons would have energy and all. What forbids it is the fact that **a static configuration of charges can't be stable** (that is, it is guaranteed to fall apart if disturbed). That's a mathematical result known as [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem). So it was obvious to Bohr that the electrons must be moving in some way or another.

Now what about the orbits? Well, a single particle in a bound system with Coulomb-like potential can only go in circular (or, more generally, elliptical) orbits. It was known for centuries thanks to Newton and celestial mechanics, which just happens to use a potential of the same form. None of this was left for Bohr to guess. He used a well-known kind of motion in a different setting. (Elliptical orbits appear in the so-called Bohr–Sommerfeld model, but that's not much of a thing.)

Well, now what if we have *more than one* electron? **Nothing.** Bohr's model does not describe such systems.

So it goes.

Comment: RE: *changing the tag to "history of chemistry", because that's the only context in which Bohr's model is still relevant.* -- That seems a bit harsh. I'd assume that the Bohr model is still used to introduce quantization in a general chemistry course along with atomic line spectra. Then that model would be further built on.

Comment: I'd put it differently. The Bohr model is used to mentally break the students and thus prepare them for the worst. Then it is discarded and never further built on. The real quantum theory is then built from scratch.

Comment: On the contrary, I think the Bohr model can still give us useful basic intuition. As an example, Batty uses it as an effective theory to describe exotic atoms at CERN "We now discuss, using the classical Bohr model, the general characteristics of antiprotonic-hydrogen atoms". (C.J. Batty, Rep. Prog. Phys. 52 (1989), p1169)